# catch data that creates a table with only one non-empty row or column in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am doing a `chisq.test` on a bunch variables but it unexpectedly failed with:

```
Error in chisq.test(var1, var2) : 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

A quick examination yields that:

```
> table(var1,var2)
    var2
var1    1    2    3    4    5    6
   0   34   48  153  710 1667 2177
   1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

So the contingency table has a row that is empty and is left with just one row. How can I do a test for such variables and skip them in my loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nlevels` to get the number of levels in a factor. For instance, you could do something like this:

```
if (nlevels(var1) > 1 & nlevels(var2) > 1) {
    chisq.test(var1, var2)
} else {
    warning('Not enough levels to perform chi-sq test.')
}
```

Comment: But both variables have more than one level. It just happens that when they are crosstabulated that one of the rows of the table ends up empty. (because every case where var1 has a value of 1, var2 has NA)

Comment: You can treat `NA` as a level by passing your factors to `addNA`. For example, try `chisq.test(addNA(var1), addNA(var2))`.

Comment: But that's not what I want to do. I want something like:     if(can't do chisq test with var1 and var2) { #code } else { #other code }